# Blurry text in KDE settings app

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, kde

[image: Example of blurry text]

I just installed Kubuntu 17.04 and in the system settings app provided with Kubuntu has a graphical glitch as shown; some text is fine but some text is blurry (it can't be read). It's blurry in multiple locations in settings app (no other app if affected by this (to my knowledge).

I don't have an Nvidia or AMD card so it can't be a graphics driver problem in my opinion.

I've no idea how to fix this!